# Unknown python error calling a method in another class "Cannot Log Error"

Tags: python, class, exception

I have a main Python class and helper classes.  One of these helps with file operations, another with getting data out of files.  I am getting a "Cannot log error" in python whenever I call one method, no matter if I change the name of it, move it to a different class or whatever.  There's utterly no rhyme or reason.  I have even cut the method to just simply return a True and Text argument back and it still cannot run.

I cut the code down to just return a boolean and string and do no processing whatsoever

```
ret, charsreturned = self.flutils.getStuff(fullpath, self.limit)

def getStuff(self, pathtofile, limit=500):
    try:
        ret = True
        crap = "no file data"
        return ret, crap
    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
        return False, "everything is to crap."
```

I should return "True" and "no file data"

I am simply getting Cannot Log error on the console - I cannot catch the error or anything.

Comment: Please add the stack-trace for the error... It would be more easy to figure out.

Comment: The thing with an mcve is that it must reproduce the error in a self contained manner. Even after making some guesses to make this code run, I can't get your error to show up, which means it's happening elsewhere most likely.

Comment: The stack trace is as I posted: "cannot log error"